# Will copying 'images' folder between machines be used to move images between docker hosts?

Tags: docker

I have a very slow Internet connection at office most of the times. I do have access to a cloud based Ubuntu machine where Internet connection is very fast. I would like to use this machine to bring several docker images locally and would like to download the 'images' folder to my local computer via ftp or other means. If I copy all the contents of the images folder, will my local computer be able use these images as if itself has downloaded them from Docker Hub?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Another possibility to look at is run a caching registry proxy: https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/registry-proxy-cache-docker-open-source/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** If I copy all the contents of the images folder, will my local computer be able use these images as if itself has downloaded them from Docker Hub?

**A:** Instead of copying the image files directly I would recommend using the appropriate tools to export your image. Consider using `docker save` to export your images into flat files (tar format).

**See:**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/#save

Essentially you will be doing something like 
`docker save --output busybox.tar busybox`

Then load it back into your work machine using `docker load --input busybox.tar`

**See:**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

Comment: Thanks! That makes more sense.